# 名前の語呂合わせはなんですか / Wordplay in names

Tags: meaning, word-requests, names

「オドキリ」、「キョウジュ」、「アーポン」、「ブリガミ」と「ヒルネリ」という名前のついたエルフがいます。「キョウジュ」、「ブリガミ」と「ヒルネリ」の名前の語呂合わせはわかります。「オドキリ」と「アーポン」は？?

There are elfs with names "Odokiri", "Kyouju", "Aapon", "Burigami" and "Hiruneri". I understand the wordplay of names "Kyouju", "Burigami" and "Hiruneri". ヒルネリ => 昼寝 (this elf likes to sleep) ブリガミ => ぶりぶり + がみがみ (this elf often in bad mood) キョウジュ => 教授 (this elf is very smart). I'm trying to understand the meaning of other names  - "Odokiri" (maybe from おどおど or 驚く) and "Aapon" (doesn't have distinguishing feature, 普通).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I fixed your question because hiragana and katakana are mixed up in some of the names. I hope I could have managed to make what you wanted to ask more clearer.

Comment: I googled with these names and found nothing relevant. I have no idea what キョウジュ, ブリガミ or ヒルネリ would mean. In addition, usually elves are creatures in western fantasy, not that of Japanese. (I happen to know elves in [DQX](https://dragonquest.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Quest_X) have Japanese-like names, but is it what you are talking about?)

Comment: ヒルネリ  => 昼寝 (this elf likes to sleep) ブリガミ => ぶりぶり + がみがみ (this elf often in bad mood) キョウジュ => 教授 (this elf is very smart)... I'm trying to understand the meaning of other names.

Comment: kimi Tanaka, thank you! ))

Comment: @Sever81 Please add the information to your original question and let us know what kind of character do「オドキリ 」and 「アーポン」have. I think it makes the people answer more easily.

Answer (score 2):

I guess 「オドキリ 」is composed of onomatopoeia「オドオド」: "Because they are getting nervous, they look uneasy/restless"  + 「[ドッキリ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A/)」」: "they are getting surprised because it's unexpected." And concatenate them altogether into the  ligature-like name 「オドキリ 」. It seems "he is not confident" in total.

I have no idea about what「アーポン」means. I can find an idol called[「あーぽん」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B2%96%E7%94%B0%E5%BD%A9%E8%8F%AF), the nickname of 「[彩華](あやか）. Is real name still hid like her? Or the name describes elf's appearance rather than their personality?

I think you have correctly analyzed other elfs' wordplay.

Comment: kimi Tanaka, ok, thank you!